# Why My AVD is not having proper functionality

Tags: java, android, android-virtual-device

There is no menu icon in my Avd. I can't see all the available option in my Avd also here in my device internet is always showing disconnected. Can any one help me out regarding this.[image: this screen shows i am always disconnect from internet][image: This is always i am getting on home screen][image: I want a a avd which show me this screen]
The last screen i attached here is what all i want.
It is proper.the first 2 screen i attached is from my machine.But the last one is not from my machine.Why i am unable to generate the same UI for avd in my machine.

Comment: For what about you have created AVD? Android Wear? It is for Android Wear.

Comment: i created it for running my android app.I need a screen like the last one.But for me in my machine its not coming there @pratik

Comment: @sashikanta Did my answer below solve your problem ?

Comment: I appreciate your answer.But still i didn't get the same screen as i expected.As show in my last attachment.@Outofmemory

Comment: @sashikanta I have edited my answer, Please see if the below helps you or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have created AVD for **Wearable** devices. I assume that you are creating an AVD for smart phones. Please see this
[image]

Make sure you have downloaded the API level 17,18,19 packages. If not Navigate in Eclipse to `Window - >Android SDK Manager` and download the API packages as shown in the below image

Click on the checkboxes `Android 4.4.2`, `Android 4.3.1` and `Android 4.2.2` to download
[image]

Comment: why i am not getting the same option there in target even after choosing the same device. aPI 16/17/19 IS not available.